# How to fill string missing values in specific column with condition based on row after in python?

Tags: python, pandas, exploratory-data-analysis

I'd like to fill string missing values in one column with condition based on row after in python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s8Fw.png)

The missing values should have different value with the row after (if we see it with timely perspective), so it should be connect -> disconnect -> connect and so on.
So in this case here I would like to have the `Monitoring Desc` missing values to be filled with "disconnect", as the row after is "connect".

I've tried:
`df['Monitoring Desc'] = df['Monitoring Desc'].fillna(np.where(df['Monitoring Desc'].shift(1) == "ws_connect", "ws_disconnect", "ws_connect"))`

but showed error message:
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "ndarray"

I'm not do this kind of analysis in python, so I can't think of anything else. Maybe there is something to do with loop or function to fill these missing values?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

plz provide input as text table not image.

mapping reverse and ffill

```
m = {'ws_connect':'ws_disconnect', 'ws_disconnect':'ws_connect'}
df['Monitoring Desc'] = df['Monitoring Desc'].fillna(df['Monitoring Desc'].map(m).ffill())
```

df

```
        Monitoring Desc datetime
3956    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 21:00
3955    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 20:00
1336    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 19:58
3954    ws_connect      2023-11-01 19:00
1363    ws_connect      2023-11-01 18:00
1364    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 18:00
1365    ws_connect      2023-11-01 18:00
3953    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 18:00
3952    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 17:00
3951    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 16:00
3950    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 15:00
3949    ws_disconnect   2023-11-01 14:00
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Monitoring Desc': {3956: 'ws_disconnect', 3955: 'ws_disconnect', 1336: 'ws_disconnect', 
                             3954: 'ws_connect', 1363: 'ws_connect', 1364: 'ws_disconnect', 
                             1365: 'ws_connect', 3953: 'ws_disconnect', 3952: 'ws_disconnect', 
                             3951: 'ws_disconnect', 3950: 'ws_disconnect', 3949: 'ws_disconnect'}, 
         'datetime': {3956: '2023-11-01 21:00', 3955: '2023-11-01 20:00', 1336: '2023-11-01 19:58', 
                      3954: '2023-11-01 19:00', 1363: '2023-11-01 18:00', 1364: '2023-11-01 18:00', 
                      1365: '2023-11-01 18:00', 3953: '2023-11-01 18:00', 3952: '2023-11-01 17:00', 
                      3951: '2023-11-01 16:00', 3950: '2023-11-01 15:00', 3949: '2023-11-01 14:00'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the image input...
It works and applied to other missing rows, thank you good sir!